# What happened to Devices -> Cameras in Windows 10 settings?

Tags: windows-10, webcam

My USB webcam is too dark and I wanted to change its settings without installing any closed source software from the manufacturer.

I'm trying to find information about Win 10 settings that could change the brightness of webcams. Curiously, there was a setting for that, but I think it's gone now? [What ever happened to this setting](https://www.intowindows.com/how-to-change-camera-settings-in-windows-10/)?

[image: Devices > Cameras]

I can't find that "Cameras" settings, even though the camera driver is certainly installed and I have the latest Windows update. I tried finding it in both Win 10 Home and Pro, but it's nowhere to be found.

I guess I'll need to use [ffmpeg](https://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/access-advanced-settings-for-the-integrated-webcam-on-windows-10/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regrettably, MS has removed most of these setting from the control panels, though if you have the MS *Camera* application installed (it is packaged with Windows), some global settings can be adjusted with it.

However, [How2Do](https://how2do.org/how-to-adjust-webcam-settings-contrast-and-brightness-on-windows-pc/) suggests a third-party application, [Webcam Settings Tool](https://www.softpedia.com/dyn-postdownload.php/065d8c3d3c2dde675687a2494fac3375/610b5b08/4063c/0/1), about 6 MB for the zipped portable version, screenshot below. There are [many alternatives](https://webcam-settings-control-full-camera-adjustment.en.softonic.com/mac/alternatives), as well. Before installing *any* application, check it for malware at [VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/home/upload) or elsewhere.

[image: Webcam Settings Tool]

Though Windows may miss the mark in some areas, at least it is *currently* an open platform, allowing third-party tools such as Webcam Settings Tool and  [Open-Shell Menu](https://open-shell.github.io/Open-Shell-Menu/) to make amends.